# how to improve performance of oculus?

Tags: oculus-rift, virtual-reality

I know about tweaking the supersampling, but what about hardware?

Will better hardware help? Will a graphics card do better? what about the rest (processor and memory frequency)?

Right now, the oculus experience is kinda a bummer dude on a GTX 970 with an I7-4790. What can I do to make it better?

Comment: Sweet rig!  Which games are running poorly?  Also, how much RAM?

Comment: You'd probably have to check the system requirements for each game to see what they say for VR.  VR is usually more taxing, since it usually has to double the framerate (one frame for each eye, instead of one frame for both eyes.)

Comment: indeed.  specs articles reveal a pc that can run 4k @ 90Hz is needed. min gtx 970,  which i have,  is a bit on the low side from experience,  although it is the recommended card ; games quality might suffer with the official recommended specs. need to keep in mind that there are 2 screens that need 2k @ 90Hz and that your sickness level increases fast with poor performance. iracing and assetto corsa where challenging for me

Comment: Add a second card in SLI?  Does that card have 8gb of video ram? A ssd might offer a boost in certain conditions.